# Error when opening a new downloaded Office file

Tags: excel, windows-10, window, ms-office

I download an Office file(eg.Excel,Word) from internet and open it in my local computer. It will raise a error message
"Microsoft Excel cannot open or save any more documents because there is not enough available memory or disk space. [...].".

The file is in protected view if it is downloaded from internet.
Disabling Protected View allows the files to be opened.  But this is not a solution.  We need the protection of Protected View.
Also, my computer has plenty of free hard drive space and RAM.

Anyone has idea on this issue in Office?

I have reinstalled the Office but the problem still exist.

Comment: Try reinstalling msOffice

Comment: I have reinstalled the msOffice but still not work

Comment: What version of office is it

Comment: i am using Office 2016

Answer (score 0):

Goto file -> right click -> properties 
Attributes -> unblock in attribute section

Comment: I think this is a temporary workaround but not a solution. It requires to do this action every time when i download a new excel from internet.

Comment: Do u know why the Office raise this error? Any setting can fix this problem that can keep the protection view when opening a new downloaded excel?

Comment: It is usually due to mismatch of the version of Office you have and the version of office used while creating the file. So maybe having a generalized solution will be difficult.